# Any tips on backporting merge() operation from Hibernate 3 to a custom Hibernate 2 application?

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, interceptor

I'm currently trying to perform audit logging of changed properties using an `Interceptor` in Hibernate 2.x.

Problem is, the entity I'm trying to save is a detached object so the `previousState` array in `onFlushDirty` method of `Interceptor` always return null. They say that this can be simply solved by calling `merge` but that method is not available in Hibernate 2.x. Any tips on how I can workaround the problem?

Also, would you have any ideas on how easy or how hard it is to implement something like `merge` in an application running Hibernate 2.x?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 2.x, have you tried using `saveOrUpdate(Object)`? This was the initial workaround provided by Hibernate until they added `merge()` in Hibernate 3.